# What is an Organizable Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Organizable Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Organizable Words™ | Not Organizable Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BEINGS | PEOPLE |
| BOOTS | SHOES |
| CASE | CHASE |
| ELBOW | KNEE |
| GOTHS | MOTHS |
| RIFTS | GIFTS |
| SADDER | LADDER |
| SHILL | SHELL |
| SHIP | BOAT |
| SLOGS | LOGS |
| SLOT | SLOW |
| TAPED | TIED |
| TON | POUND |
| WONK | NERD |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
Organizable Words™,Not Organizable Words™
BEINGS,PEOPLE
BOOTS,SHOES
CASE,CHASE
ELBOW,KNEE
GOTHS,MOTHS
RIFTS,GIFTS
SADDER,LADDER
SHILL,SHELL
SHIP,BOAT
SLOGS,LOGS
SLOT,SLOW
TAPED,TIED
TON,POUND
WONK,NERD
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is an Organizable Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Organizable Words™, many more exist.

Comment: I have troubles organizing people and shoes as well. And specially nerds.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An Organizable Word is

> one that remains a word when alphabetized.

Below is a list of the example words that shows how they are Organizable:

> BEINGS => BEGINS;
>  BOOTS => BOOST;
>  CASE => ACES;
>  ELBOW => BELOW;
>  GOTHS => GHOST;
>  RIFTS => FIRST;
>  SADDER => ADDERS;
>  SHILL => HILLS;
>  SHIP => HIPS;
>  SLOGS => GLOSS;
>  SLOT => LOST
>  TAPED => ADEPT;
>  TON => NOT;
>  WONK => KNOW;