# What is an Angered Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Angered Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Angered Words™ | Not Angered Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ENGLISH | CHINESE |
| STACK | PILE |
| TABLE | DESK |
| SHIP | BOAT |
| STABLE | WOBBLY |
| SPEAK | TALK |
| READ | LOOK |
| TIME | CLOCK |
| TRADE | EXCHANGE |
| CAR | MOTORCYCLE |

CSV Version:

```
Angered Words™,Not Angered Words™
ENGLISH,CHINESE
STACK,PILE
TABLE,DESK
SHIP,BOAT
STABLE,WOBBLY
SPEAK,TALK
READ,LOOK
TIME,CLOCK
TRADE,EXCHANGE
CAR,MOTORCYCLE
```

Hint:

> If a word is not an Angered Word™, then none of its anagrams can be an Angered Word™.

These are not the only examples of Angered Words™, many more exist.

**What is the rule, and how about the name?**

---

<sup>This is not a duplicate of [What is an Organizable Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48505/what-is-an-organizable-word). No offense, @Oray, but if you had just looked at the first example, *eghilns* is **not** a word.</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an Organizable Word™?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48505/what-is-an-organizable-word)

Comment: @Oray Nope. It's different.

Comment: i cant see the difference, both is anagram question of a given word?

Comment: The right hand side should probably have had more counterexamples as confirmers.

Comment: @Oray No offense, but if you had just looked at the first example, eghilns is not a word.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An Angered Word™

> is one that has a (common) English anagram where no letter ends up in the same position. These words anagram to SHINGLE, TACKS, BLEAT, HIPS, PEAKS, DARE, EMIT, RATED, and ARC.

The title is "Angered" because

> ANGERED is an anagram of DERANGE, and these types of permutations (where nothing ends up where it started) are called derangements.

Comment: I read the title and assumed Angered was a cryptic anagram indicator, due to all the cryptic clues we've had recently

Comment: You forgot to mention that WORDS also has an anagram, SWORD; and also NOT (TON).

Comment: ™, on the other hand, isn’t an anagram of anything.

Comment: **\*SPOILER:\*** It should also be mentioned that PILE is an anagram of _lipe_ (and TILE of _lite_; the image and the CSV version are different here), BOAT of _bota_, and LOOK of _kolo_. None of those are particularly common words (except _lite_, especially in American English), but they are in normal dictionaries. So if this is indeed the intended solution, the question is what constitutes ‘common’.

Comment: @Deusovi It is now correct.